# Redirect https from root directory to sub directory

Tags: web, redirect, https

I want to redirect from **https://www.example.net** to **https://www.example.net/dd**
but I cannot find any solution to do this.

Comment: Try adding more detail to your question. Is this a web page or a back end? What language are you using? I posted the line in javascript as the answer, let me know.

Comment: In its current for it is impossible to answer to the question. It is completely unclear what situation you have. You need to revise your question, add more details so that we can understand what you actually ask. There is an ``edit`` link below your question. _Use it..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to the .htaccess
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dd

It did not work before because I have not enable mod_rewrite, so I typed in 
**sudo a2enmod rewrite**.

Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.replace("https://www.example.net/dd");`.